# SQL - Return results only if 3 events exist in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

hoping to get some help with my query below.

What I need, is results returned ONLY IF all 3 event id's exist from the one table.

A Terminal ID can have multiple event ID's associated to it in this table. 
I'm only looking for the Terminal ID's which have 3 particular events in there within the specified date range:

The below query returns Terminal ID's that have any one of the three event id's and i'm not sure how to tell it to get what I need.

```
SELECT
 EJTM.terminal_id

FROM
 IG_LOG..EJ_Terminal_Master EJTM
 JOIN it_sysweb..EJ_Tran_Event_Master EJEM ON EJTM.event_type_id = EJEM.EJ_tran_event_id

WHERE
 EJEM.EJ_tran_event_id in 
(
 5011 --SignOn
,5119 --Reinit Printer
,5101 --NoSale 
 )                          
AND
 EJTM.event_date_time between '2017-06-06 03:00:00.000' and '2017-06-08 03:00:00.000'
AND
 EJEM.language_id = 'EN-US'

GROUP BY
 EJTM.terminal_id
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? MySQL or SQL Server? Remove whichever tag is not needed. Adding more tags will not get your question answered faster.

Comment: You could group by eventid and then add having count(terminal_id) = 3

Comment: HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT EJEM.EJ_tran_event_id) =3

Comment: Thanks for your input all! 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT EJEM.EJ_tran_event_id) =3
was the answer! Big help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `GROUP BY` with `COUNT`, e.g.:

```
SELECT tm.terminal_id
FROM IG_LOG..EJ_Terminal_Master.tm JOIN it_sysweb..EJ_Tran_Event_Master em
ON tm.event_type_id = em.EJ_tran_event_id
WHERE em.EJ_tran_event_id IN (5011, 5119, 5101)
AND em.event_date_time between '2017-06-06 03:00:00.000' AND '2017-06-08 03:00:00.000'
AND em.language_id = 'EN-US'
GROUP BY tm.terminal_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT em.EJ_tran_event_id) = 3;
```

Comment: Thanks Darshan. This is exactly what i needed!

Answer (score 1):

Although bit robust, using and clause will work

```
WHERE
      EJEM.EJ_tran_event_id = '5011' --SignOn
 AND  EJEM.EJ_tran_event_id = '5119' --Reinit Printer
 AND EJEM.EJ_tran_event_id = '5101' --NoSale                        
 AND
 EJTM.event_date_time between '2017-06-06 03:00:00.000' and '2017-06-08 03:00:00.000'
 AND
 EJEM.language_id = 'EN-US'
```

Comment: Thanks B House! Ended up using the:
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT EJEM.EJ_tran_event_id) =3